Printing clist out, but controlling whether there should be a \nobreakspace after “and”
I have a pretty dynamic CV. I have a lot of \if...s at the top controlling what the CV is for. If I want to stress that I have experience with Microsoft Dynamics 365, I set \ifdynamics to true. If I want to apply for positions that involve data science, I set \ifdataanalyst to true. And so on.
Then at some point, I have to explain what it is that I can do, Oxford-comma style. The easiest way to do this seems to be to create a command \printclist which can print out a comma-separated list with an “and” towards the end. So something like this:
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdynamics
\dynamicstrue

\newif\ifdataanalyst
\dataanalysttrue

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_use:nnnn { ennn }

\NewDocumentCommand { \printclist } { m }{
    \clist_use:ennn { #1 } { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and\nobreakspace }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

I have experience with \printclist{
    \noexpand\LaTeX,
    Java,
    C\#,
    HTML,
    CSS,
    Python,
    \ifdataanalyst SQL\fi,
    \ifdynamics Microsoft Dynamics~365\fi
}.

\end{document}


The \nobreakspace is there because I don’t want a line break before some short entry like SQL. But a line break before something longer, like “Microsoft Dynamics 365”, wouldn’t be an issue. And as you see, with these settings, the \nobreakspace causes an ugly hyphenation of “Microsoft”.
So how do I design a good, robust interface where I can specify for each entry in the list whether or not there should be a \nobreakspace between it and “and”? The cleanest solution I can think of would be to prefix those where I want it with a ~, so something like this:
\printclist{
    \noexpand\LaTeX,
    ~Java,
    ~C\#,
    ~HTML,
    ~CSS,
    Python,
    \ifdataanalyst~SQL\fi,
    \ifdynamics Microsoft Dynamics~365\fi
}.

How do I accomplish this without breaking something else with the command or accidentally killing all fragile commands?

e-expanding the clist looks very suspicious and definitely not very idiomatic l3, it's forcing you to use \noexpand and also use primitive \if tokens, I would just have a list of subjects and specify elsewhere which subjects are included in which set, otherwise  items that need to be included for more than one \ifxxx  will get increasing convoluted entries.

@DavidCarlisle Fair point. I guess I could also simply define a clist and then add or not add something to it inside an \if statement. But that leaves the issue of the \nobreakspace or ordinary space after “and”.

You could put some command there that looks ahead and uses nobreakspace if the following item is less than 3 letters or typesets to less than 2em or whatever

@DavidCarlisle How am I supposed to check whether something is 3 letters without fully expanding it? Anyway, I am completely satisfied with specifying this manually, e.g. by prefixing those entries with ~.

do you ever want to hyphenate? why use nobreakspace at all, just use a normal space and disable hyphenation for the list

@DavidCarlisle I don’t want a break before SQL or similar short entries.

sorry that;s what you said, yes I forgot the thread:-) but I would still just have a list of the entries and break or not depending on a measured length or looking up a list of no-break words

@DavidCarlisle Anyway, do you like my posted solution better?

yes I gave you a vote:-)

@DavidCarlisle Votes are supposed to be secret.

that's OK: no one is listening

You can decide for a special character that's not expected at the beginning of such strings, here + and prefix the item with it in case you don't want \nobreakspace if the item is the last one.
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdynamics
\dynamicstrue

\newif\ifdataanalyst
\dataanalysttrue

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\newdynlist { m }
 {
  \clist_new:c { g__gaussler_dynlist_#1_clist }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\addtodynlist { mm }
 {
  \clist_put_right:cn { g__gaussler_dynlist_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\printdynlist { m }
 {
  \clist_use:cnnn { g__gaussler_dynlist_#1_clist }
   { ~ and ~ \__gaussler_dynlist_ignore: }
   { , ~ \__gaussler_dynlist_ignore: }
   { , ~ and \__gaussler_dynlist_nobreak: }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gaussler_dynlist_ignore:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NF + {} % just ignore a +
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gaussler_dynlist_nobreak:
 {
  \peek_charcode_remove:NTF + { ~ } { \nobreakspace } % if no +, \nobreakspace
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newdynlist{competencies}

\addtodynlist{competencies}{
    \LaTeX,
    Java,
    C\#,
    HTML,
    CSS,
    Python
}

\ifdataanalyst
    \addtodynlist{competencies}{SQL}
\fi

\ifdynamics
    \addtodynlist{competencies}{+Microsoft Dynamics~365}
\fi

I have experience with \printdynlist{competencies}.

\end{document}


If the item prefixed with + doesn't happen to be last, nothing happens
If I replace with
\ifdynamics
    \addtodynlist{competencies}{Microsoft Dynamics~365}
\fi

the output would be

and you see that \nobreakspace has been inserted.
If you really want to use ~ instead of +, you can modify the auxiliary functions to
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gaussler_dynlist_ignore:
 {
  \exp_after:wN \peek_charcode_remove:NF \c_tilde_str {} % just ignore a +
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gaussler_dynlist_nobreak:
 {
  % if no ~ at the beginning, \nobreakspace
  \exp_after:wN \peek_charcode_remove:NF \c_tilde_str { ~ } { \nobreakspace }
 }

because a real ~ is needed: in the scope of \ExplSyntaxOn, ~ has category code 10 and so it is ignored after a control sequence, so we need to provide it in a different fashion. However, I don't find that inputting ~ when you don't want a tie is quite misleading. I chose + to tell users “this is a long item”.

As it just happens, + can occurs in such strings, e.g. in C++. I think I’d prefer something along the lines of the original suggestion: prefixing those where I want a no-break space with ~.

But then again, ~ can also occur, e.g. with Microsoft Dynamics~365.

@Gaussler Does the + appear at the beginning? Only the first character is checked upon.

That's what I thought, but your first sentence suggested otherwise.

But if I wanted to use ~, how could I do that? I tried \peek_charcode_remove:NTF ^^7e { \nobreakspace } { ~ }, didn’t seem to work.

@Gaussler Do you really want to type in ~ when you don't want a tie in the final output? Anyway, ^^7e is the same as ~ which has category code 10 in the scope of \ExplSyntaxOn.

@Gaussler I reworded the paragraph about + and added the trick to use ~ instead. But read the final comment about syntax.

I get that, I wanted to do the reverse, i.e. use ~ to suggest “I want a \nobreakspace”. But whatever, your solution works. Thanks!

Based on my discussion with @DavidCarlisle, I thought of the following solution to my own problem. That being said, I’d still love to see other solutions with different approaches.
Instead, I now define a command \newdynlist{⟨name⟩} which creates a “dynamic list” of entries with name ⟨name⟩. Then I define a command \addtodynlist{⟨name⟩}{⟨entries⟩}. But it supports an optional star. If I do \addtodynlist*{⟨name⟩}{⟨entries⟩}, then if this is the last entry to be added to the dynamic list, it will suppress the \nobreakspace when the dynamic list is printed out. If there is no star, a \nobreakspace will be used.
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifdynamics
\dynamicstrue

\newif\ifdataanalyst
\dataanalysttrue

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\newdynlist { m } {
    \clist_new:c { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_#1 }
    \bool_new:c { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_no_break_space_#1_bool }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\addtodynlist { smm } {
    \clist_put_right:cn { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_#2 } { #3 }
    \IfBooleanTF { #1 } {
        \bool_set_false:c { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_no_break_space_#2_bool }
    } {
        \bool_set_true:c { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_no_break_space_#2_bool }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\printdynlist { m } {
    \bool_if:cTF { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_no_break_space_#1_bool } {
        \clist_use:cnnn { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_#1 } { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and\nobreakspace }
    } {
        \clist_use:cnnn { g__gaussler_dynamic_list_#1 } { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newdynlist{competencies}

\addtodynlist*{competencies}{
    \LaTeX,
    Java,
    C\#,
    HTML,
    CSS,
    Python
}

\ifdataanalyst
    \addtodynlist{competencies}{SQL}
\fi

\ifdynamics
    \addtodynlist*{competencies}{Microsoft Dynamics~365}
\fi

I have experience with \printdynlist{competencies}.

\end{document}


